# Chaining two batteries to achieve a specific voltage range under their maximum

Tags: voltage, batteries, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider, shift-register

I'm building a portable 8x8 LED matrix powered off of two CR2450 coin cell batteries. Most of my components ( Attiny85 and LEDs ) can run easily off of the supply voltage range of the CR2450, but the shift registers aren't being as conducive...

There are three shift registers in my design: two DM7495N and one NTE74LS164. All three shift registers have a recommended voltage range of 4.75 to 5.25 in order to operate. If I chained the two batteries, they would supply a maximum voltage output of 6V and a minimum of maybe a little over 5.2V, before the other components become under-powered and the batteries would need to be replaced. That is not within the range associated with the shift registers..;(

Is there a really simple way to step down the voltage to fit the ratings of the shift registers without using a voltage divider? Like maybe with a couple of resistors or some other common electronics component? Something tells me that there is in this case, since I am using two separate batteries... If I have to, I could ignore the recommended ratings, as both registers have a maximum input voltage larger than 6V, but I would like to know if there is an efficient and easy way to step the voltage down in this case. Thanks!

Comment: No one is answering :(

Comment: I'd avoid all the regulator hassle and go for devices that can handle the voltage. CD4035 or some HC device?

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to think a regulator would be a little over-kill, too... I was mainly wondering if it was possible to easily adjust the voltage output of two chained batteries by chaining them in some special way or something...

Comment: Have you seen the [datasheet](https://na.industrial.panasonic.com/sites/default/pidsa/files/crseries_datasheets_merged.pdf) for the cell you've selected? The "continuous standard load" is just 0.2 mA. How many LEDs are you hoping to drive with that?

Comment: Oh no.. I didn't see that. Do you think it would vary much depending on the manufacturer? The battery I'm using doesn't have that type of information on it. Could it handle 80mA or 40mA, maybe 90mA? Lol, I'm new to electronics..

Comment: I'm using two of them. Would that lighten the load on each one individually?

Comment: I'll power either 4 LEDs or 2 LEDs, depending on brightness when I test this out... They consume 20mA each. The rest of the matrix should consume a relatively small amount of current in comparison, I'm assuming.

Comment: So yeah, this thing should have a pretty short battery life, lol..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend changing the parts in your design to use parts such as the 74HC195 and 74HC164, or change the design slightly to use other variants of CMOS technology.

The 74HC parts operate over the range of 2-6V and consume hardly any power, much less than those you are currently using - they could operate without any regulator. They can interface with the ATtiny the same as the TTL and LS parts and are pin compatible.

The static power consumption of CMOS devices is close to zero - for example the 74HC164 has a typical value of only 8uA at 25°C.

When the device is operating there will be additional current required to charge the internal capacitances that depend upon both the power supply voltage and the operating frequency.

The data sheet usually has a value called "Power Dissipation Capacitance" or similar - this is 40pF for the 74HC164. This can be used to calculate the dynamic power consumption. (See page 9, note 3 of the [datasheet for the 74HC164](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT164.pdf)).

If the device is operating at low frequencies this will be very low.  For example if the 74HC164 is being clocked at 1MHz with a 5v supply and the input data is a constant zero or 1 the resulting supply current will be 1mA, much less than the 30mA of the 74LS164.

40*(5)^2 * 10^6 * 10^-12 = 10^-3 = 1mA.

I would expect the average frequency when used for driving a display to be in the kHz range with a correspondingly low current consumption.

Any current required to be sourced from the output pins would be added to this currents.  Sinking current does not require any additional supply current.

Comment: That'd be a good idea... I might do that in the next iteration of the matrix... For now I'm thinking about just supplying the 6V. That's still a volt under what the NTE register can handle and far under the max for the DM7495Ns can. For most of the batteries life, they would supply less than six volts anyways...

Comment: The CMOS ones are pin compatible with the ones you are using, so they only require substituting the new parts.

Comment: Oh really... You know you're right. It may only take a couple of days for these components to ship from Amazon anyways... I'll try ordering something. Thanks!

Comment: How exactly is power consumption measured with these things? Like how do I know how much current I need to supply the shift register in order to achieve a certain current output from the pins?

Comment: I've added how to calculate the supply current.

Comment: Would this make more sense if I had a better understanding how shift registers are designed ( and maybe electronics in general. I don't really understand how capacitance works in ICs like this, ATM )? It sounds like I do not have to worry about the power consumption of the 74HC164, because I only plan at driving it at somewhere between 1MHz and 8MHz for 12 clock cycles ( to load the shift register with its values ) and then basically having it sit for 1 or 2 milliseconds throughout the rasterization processes.

Answer (score 2):

This arrangement will not work at all, not even for a short time.

The CR2450 battery (per Sony, Panasonic datasheets) has a drop of ~100 mV with a load of 7.5k, or 0.4 mA. This means that the internal battery resistance is about 250 Ohms. Even if you try 4 LEDs at 2 mA each, the voltage will drop by 2-3 V. Your Attiny will eat another 1 mA even if you run it at 1MHz. The main killler will be DM7495 with typical consumption of 50 (!!!) mA. Two of them will take 100 mA, plus 17 mA for NTE74LS164. There is no way for these batteries to deliver 120mA, the short current (voltage drop to zero) will be ~12-15 mA.

So scrap your project and start over, with CMOS chips as Kevin suggested, and a different battery.

Comment: The recommended max supply current for the DM7495N is 75 mA. I saw the typical 250mW dissapation, but how do you determine 50mA from that? That seems like a lot? Sorry if these are stupid questions. I'm new to electronics...

Comment: Also the LEDs are run in parallel. This thing is charleplexed. So where are you getting a 2-3 volt drop?

Comment: From Energizer datasheet, http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/cr2450.pdf they list 9mA at 2.7 V, making internal resistance about 33 Ohms. So the battery can deliver max 100mA at zero volts, for 2 seconds. Zero volts is not what you want. The 50 mA is "typical" for DM7495. I am really curious, where did you get these ancient parts?

Comment: Lol, that's understandable.. ;) I just really wanted to make an led matrix so I used what I could scavenge at a local makerspace.

Comment: @Holden Reconsider using AA(A) batteries in combination with a boost converter. (or buck/boost depending on the amount of cells)

Comment: Ok, I think you're right about the shift registers... I'm supplying it varying amounts of current and it seems that only a fraction of that is being output on the pins. I'll have to get some new shift registers. That seems crazy to me, though... Where is all the current going? That may be a totally different question entirely... The battery is holding up fine, though. I had it run 4 LEDs at 16mA each, as a test. I didn't test it at 100mA, but once I have all the components sorted out, I don't think each battery should need to supply more than 50mA. (Continued ...)

Comment: If I needed to I could I could run the shift registers at really low currents and have their outputs connected to the bases of transistors. That should minimize inefficiency, I would think... I don't think that would be necessary with new CMOS chips, though...

Comment: I'm set on using the CR2450 form factor. I have already designed this thing to be laser cut and one of its coolest features is the battery compartment. I'm not too worried about battery life, because I don't plan on running this thing continuously for that long, anyways.

Comment: Would you recommend any type of special component for letting current through from the cathode rows of the matrix? I was going to have the 8-bit NTE connect to the bases of 8 transistors, but now I could consider a different approach... The only constraint is that the IC needs to be controllable with only 2 lines, (like the shift register is now).

Comment: @Holden If the batteries are in series then the current will still need to be 100mA through both.  If you are really set on using the CR2450 form factor you are going to have a lot of trouble running the device for any reasonable amount of time.

Comment: They should only need to be run in parallel, now that I am going to use a shift register better suited for the application that doesn't need the larger voltage. I'm starting to think of some ways to conserve power. I'll probably be able to dim the LEDs a little bit from 20 milliamps. Also, the CMOS shift registers will not require much current, from what it is sounding like. The Attiny will be sleeping whenever it is not loading a shift register, which is the majority of the time. 12/14 cycles vs. 1 millisecond or 2 milliseconds. Also, at any given time maybe around half of the LEDs won't even

Comment: be powered on. So I'm starting to think that this thing may actually have a somewhat not terrible battery life... Anything wrong with my logic?

Comment: By LEDs not powered on, I mean the image displayed is not completely white; some LEDs will be turned off.

Answer (score -1):

Try searching up voltage regulators. Linear voltage regulators can do the job of stepping down the voltage but the voltage difference between the input voltage and output voltage of the linear regulator gets dissipated as heat. If you want an efficient voltage regulator, try switching voltage regulators like the Buck Converter.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that...